# High chart background and other components are not working as usual

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, background-image

I'm working on a similar project as [this-one here](http://codepen.io/sviweb/pen/AXbbdr).

```
body{
        background-image:url(http://wolf-on-wall-street.com/images/new_york_city_madness_wallp.jpg);
        -webkit-background-size:cover;
        -moz-background-size:cover;
        -o-background-size:cover;
        background-size:cover;
    }
```

I don't know why but I can't edit the page as usual... I can't add background image (I tried adding it through js and css as well), it seems that everything I add to HTML and CSS it goes straight behind the chart... I tried to erase any kind of background color in the javascript code, but still..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one:

Html

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

CSS:

```
 body{
        background-image:url(http://wolf-on-wall-street.com/images/new_york_city_madness_wallp.jpg);
        -webkit-background-size:cover;
        -moz-background-size:cover;
        -o-background-size:cover;
        background-size:cover;
    }
```

Js

```
$(function () {
    var aChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            renderTo:"container",
            plotBackgroundImage: 'http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/skies.jpg'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });

    /*change the image like------*/
aChart.options.chart.plotBackgroundImage='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/Roses_renoir.JPG';
aChart = new Highcharts.Chart(aChart.options);

});
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/JgQEc/27/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but
yepp, now the chart is not visible, just the background. I don't know how to put the chart over the background or the background behind the entire page while both being visible.

Comment: wait few minutes sir @svi

Comment: I don't know how you did that, but I see it works. I check it out on my project (hope over there it will work as well.) But Thank you anyway for now ;) !

Comment: You are Welcome Sir @svi

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ishankdubey/JgQEc/1/

```
$(function () {
var aChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        renderTo:"container",
        plotBackgroundImage: 'http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/skies.jpg'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});

/*change the image like------*/
```

aChart.options.chart.plotBackgroundImage='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/Roses_renoir.JPG';
aChart = new Highcharts.Chart(aChart.options);

});

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but I think we misunderstood each other a bit. I want to add image as a page background and not inside of the chart. If you might have any idea for it I would appreciate.

Comment: <div id="chartdiv" style="background-image:url('bg.jpg')">